# Android customize header of app

Tags: android, header

How can i customize the header of my app like the green stripe [here](http://www.google.hu/imgres?imgurl=http://downloadandroid.info/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/image15.png&imgrefurl=http://downloadandroid.info/2010/12/android-app-download-col-reminder/&usg=__mp3HGugwEy9FIAMS0Wgb9X0H7HQ=&h=480&w=320&sz=19&hl=hu&start=0&zoom=1&tbnid=WpfmBClHTILYVM%3a&tbnh=146&tbnw=97&ei=1B49TZ2yBcKCgAfG1fGdCA&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dandroid%2Breminder%26um%3D1%26hl%3Dhu%26sa%3DN%26biw%3D1280%26bih%3D923%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1&iact=rc&dur=187&oei=1B49TZ2yBcKCgAfG1fGdCA&esq=1&page=1&ndsp=46&ved=1t:429,r:22,s:0&tx=49&ty=48)?

When i start my app, its gray and slim.

Comment: its not the default header that app default header has been switched off instead the app uses a custom header which is designed as one design other GUI parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friend, this will give you complete information about tht:http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

Answer (score -1):

I think the app is in fullscreen.. Try making yours the same and you will get what you want.